How to find the probability that the object reaches $(2, 2)$ in six or fewer steps
Starting at $(0, 0)$ an object moves in coordinate plane by a sequence of steps, each of length one. each step is left, right up or down, all four equally likely. Find the probability that the object reaches $(2, 2)$ in six or fewer steps.
My Approach-
One can reach $(2,2)$ starting from the origin either by $4$ steps or $6$ steps
$2$ sub cases in $6$ step path; $3$ steps right, $1$ left, $2$ up, and $0$ down
Or $2$ steps right, $0$ left, $3$ up, $1$ down
So the required probability should be
$$\frac{\frac{4!}{2!2!}}{4^4} + \frac{\frac{6!}{3!2!1!} \cdot 2}{4^6}$$
Did multiply $2$ in the second term of the expression because of $2$ cases.
But the answer doesn’t match.
Please help!

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

The question is complete

Add your own progress to the question

Is the region bound between the square of (0,0) × (2,2)? Or the object can go anywhere and return to (2,2)

Here, I show how your answer can be simply corrected as follows:
$$\frac{\frac{4!}{2!2!}}{4^4} +  \frac{\left(\frac{6!}{3!2!1!} \color{red}{-\frac{4!}{2!2!}×2}\right) × 2}{4^6}=\frac{3}{64}.$$
Indeed, some cases in the second part includes cases already counted in the first part, that is, those paths that visit $(2,2)$ in the $4$th move and return to  $(2,2)$ again in the $6$th move.

Consider all $4^6$ possible paths of length 6.
Case 1: Object reaches $(2,2)$ in 4 steps and is not on $(2,2)$ after 6 steps:
$\binom{2}{2}$ ways for the object to get to (2,2) in 4 steps. After that, the object can head in any direction (4 possibilities) and then any direction on step 6 except for the reverse of step 5 (3 possibilities) so a total of $6\times 4\times 3=72$ possibilities.
Case 2: Object reaches $(2,2)$ in 6 steps:
The path might be UUUDRR, UURRRL.
UUUDRR has $\frac{6!}{3!2!1!}=60$ paths.
UURRRL has $\frac{6!}{3!2!1!}=60$ paths.
Total: 120 paths
Answer: 72+120=192 paths so probability is $\frac{192}{4096}=\frac{3}{64}$.

We have the six moves case to be $RRUUUD$, $RRUULR$ and its permutations.
In the first subcase of $RRUUUD$ and its permutations, we have $\frac{6!}{3!2!} = 60$ move orders.
In the second subcase, we have ${\frac{6!}{3!2!}} = 60$ move orders.
The second case where we reach $(2,2)$ in four moves and we do not end at $(2,2)$,we have $6$ possibilities for the first four moves, and then $4^2 - 4 = 12$ moves for the end. Thus, we have $6 \times 12 = 72$ move orders for this case.
In total, we have $192$ move orders, and we have $4^6$ total possibilities. Thus, the probability is $\frac{192}{4^6} = \frac{3}{64} = 4.6875\%$.

I think you mean we do not end at $(2,2)$

Yes, I meant that.

The answer is $$\frac{2\cdot6\cdot\binom 52+\binom 42\cdot4\cdot3}{4^6}=\frac3{64}.$$
We assume that the object makes exactly $6$ steps, it moves even after reaching $(2,2)$. The object is allowed to make only one step “backwards”: to the left or downwards. In this case there are $2$ ways to choose the backwards step, $6$ ways to choose its position in the overall route, and $\binom 52$ to complete the route: we choose positions for $3$ steps, opposite to the step backwards.
If the object reached the endpoint earlier, that is, after $4$ steps, then it is allowed to finish not in $(2,2)$ after $6$ steps. $4$ possible moves right after $(2,2)$, and $3$ moves afterwards (the step right back is already counted in the first summand).
Edit. The error in your reasoning is that you count twice the routes which go to $(2,2)$ in four steps and then end up in $(2,2)$ after six steps. They are included in both your summands. If you subtract the probability of these routes (equal to $\displaystyle\frac{\frac{4!}{2!\cdot2!}\cdot 4}{4^6}$), you will get the right answer.
